# What if Priority 0 Replica Set Members got newest oplog

Tags: mongodb

I got a deployment with three nodes:

```
A: priority 2, vote 1
B: priority 1, vote 1
C: priority 0, vote 1
```

In normal case, A is Primary, B/C are Secondary. Assume the at a time point, B got oplog the timestamp of which is 100, C got 110. Then A crash, What will happen exactly?

As describe in this [document](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/replica-set-priority-0-member/), Priority 0 Replica Set Members will never become primary, so I think B will become primary, but what about the data. I'm using MongoDB 4.4 BTW.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: It depends on the [Write Concern](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/write-concern/) Read the document and if you have questions, then asked it here.

Answer (score 1):

#### Expected Behaviour

In your MongoDB 4.4 scenario with:

- A: preferred primary down
- B: only available candidate for primary
- C: dedicated secondary with newest oplog

The expected outcome is that:

- B will become the new primary.
- C will [rollback writes](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/replica-set-rollbacks/) to the last oplog state in common with B so replication can resume.

... and when A eventually recovers, it will rejoin as a secondary until it catches up with B and can trigger an election to become primary again.

By default, any documents rolled back will be saved as BSON files in the `<dbpath>/rollback/<collectionUUID>/` directory on the affected replica set member. You can manually reconcile the rollback files with current data if applicable.

#### Improving Resilience

If you want to minimise potential for rollbacks I recommend setting C to the same priority as B and using a [`w:majority` write concern](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/replica-set-rollbacks/#avoid-replica-set-rollbacks).

The `w:majority` write concern ensures acknowledgement from a majority of data-bearing voting members of the replica set (which includes C in the starting config of `priority:0, vote:1`). Setting B and C to `priority:1` allows whichever member has the newest oplog entry to become primary in the event the preferred primary A is unavailable.

For a less optimal configuration you could set C to a non-zero priority lower than B (eg 0.5). In theory that would let C briefly become primary (assuming it had a later oplog entry than B) until B caught up and triggered an election due to the higher priority. In practice I think it would be better to minimise elections.

Quoting [MongoDB 4.4: Replica Set Elections](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/core/replica-set-elections/#member-priority) docs on Member Priority:

> After a replica set has a stable primary, the election algorithm will make a "best-effort" attempt to have the secondary with the highest priority available call an election. Member priority affects both the timing and the outcome of elections; secondaries with higher priority call elections relatively sooner than secondaries with lower priority, and are also more likely to win. However, a lower priority instance can be elected as primary for brief periods, even if a higher priority secondary is available. Replica set members continue to call elections until the highest priority member available becomes primary.